# tinyMCE - prevent use of original id as name / multiple instances on one page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, tinymce

**During initialisation of tinymce, can I prevent it from using the original input `id` as the `name` in the input it creates?**

I need to use multiple tinymce instances on a single page (I'm loading separate edit forms via partials on a Ruby on Rails deployment). I have multiple forms each with an `article[title]` and `article[body]` input. If I give these unique `id` then tinymce works as expected (i.e. `article-title-2`, where 2 is the unique activerecord id). If I try to select the elements using unique attributes that are not the `id` then it fails to load tinymce inputs after the first field.

```
tinyMCE.init({
  selector: '#article-title-<%= @article.id %>',
  ...
  ...
}
```

The issue is that on submission the `id` has been used as the `name` attribute, preventing RoR from recognising the field as an attribute of an article. It submits:

```
"article-title-2" => "title text"
```

instead of

```
"article" => { "title" => "title text"}
```

Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0):

**This is the solution I have come up with, but I would rather not use this work around. Improving my initialisation of `tinymce` would be much better than manually accomodating this in each model where multiple forms is a requirement. I would continue to appreciate any input or better answers! Thanks**

In the controller I manually assign the title and body parameters to the record in the `update` process:

```
def update

  ...
  @article.title = params["article-title-" + params[:id]]
  @article.body = params["article-body-" + params[:id]]
  ...

end
```

When creating a new article, where there can also be multiple new forms on a single page, I have created a random `id` in the controller action `new`. This is then submitted using a hidden field within the form (   `<%= hidden_field_tag(:random_id, @random_id) %>`) so it can be picked up again in the `create` function. This is the form `view` code:

```
<%= simple_form_for @article, remote: true do |f|  %>
  
    <h6 id="article-title-<%= @article.id.nil? ? @random_id : @article.id %>" class="tinymce-inline no-toolbar"><%= @article.title.nil? ? "Article title" : @article.title %></h6>

    <div class="tinymce-inline" id="article-body-<%= @article.id.nil? ? @random_id : @article.id %>" >
          <%= @article.body? ? @article.body.html_safe : "" %>
    </div>

    <%= hidden_field_tag(:random_id, @random_id) %>

    <%= f.submit "Save", id: "submit" %>

<% end %>
```

To ensure the random id is unique I create a random 6 character string and attach a timestamp.

```
def new

  @random_id = ('a'..'z').to_a.shuffle[0,8].join + "-" + Time.now.to_i.to_s
  ...

end

def create
  
  @article = Article.new(article_params)
  @article.title = params["article-title-" + params[:random_id]]
  @article.body = params["article-body-" + params[:random_id]]
  ...

end
```